# How do you select all rows in a database where a specific column has a value?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to find a method to select all entries in rows only where a specific column has a value

i.e.

### BOOKS

---

```
NAME                ISBN            DATE
Goldilocks          217500          12th
Rapunzel            381938
War and peace       192836          17th
```

The query i want is:

Select * from books where date has_value

So all data from rows goldilocks and war and peace would be returned because they have an entry in the date column, whereas war and peace would not

How do i implement has_value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 SELECT NAME,ISBN,DATE WHERE DATE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This presumes that the rows with empty values have null entries and aren't the empty string, but is otherwise correct.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the missed word.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE date IS NOT NULL AND TRIM(date) != ""
```

You have to take care of the columns with a `NULL` value and a possible `empty` value (if the default is not set to `NULL`).

Comment: did you mean `trim(date) != ""`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE date !=""
```

Comment: Oops, my bad. I would edit my post, but then it'd be the same as yours haha. Good call. Vote up on you.